# How to pause frame inside a while loop?

Tags: java, user-interface

I wanted to create a Frame that will be launched upon program start up. The user should input correct credentials or else the window will ask again for correct credentials. I put it inside a while loop. But the frame messed up when I ran the program. It selects different elements around the form continuously. What should I do?

```
boolean isDone = false;

    while (!isDone) {
        ap.launchFrame ();
        if (ap.isAuth) {
            isCorrect = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

isAuth on ap class is a boolean variable. It returns true when user entered correct credentials.

Comment: Where are you calling the login code? And why do you use a loop instead of just switching content (login form or success panel) based on login results? Which ui framework are you using btw?

Comment: This might be impossible to be done so easily, due to how swing (GUI) works (Threads). I encourage You to read more about **Splash Screen**, SwingWorker and threads in swing in general.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the indefinite loop is creating problems for you. Make sure you launch the frame only once.

Try

```
boolean isFrameLaunched = false;
boolean isDone = false;

while (!isDone) {
    if (!isFrameLaunched) {
        ap.launchFrame ();
        isFrameLaunched = true;
    }
    if (ap.isAuth) {
        isCorrect = true;
        break;
    }
}
```